# Sort Array based on Object Attribute - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects called `canvasObjects`.

Each object has an attribute called `z`.

I want to sort this array based on objects `z`. How do I do this using the `sort()` method?

Answer (score 32):

You just need to pass in a comparator to the sort function

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.attr < b.attr)
     return -1;
  if (a.attr > b.attr)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

canvasObjects.sort(compare);
```

Or inline

```
canvasObjects.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.attr > b.attr) ? 1 : ((b.attr > a.attr) ? -1 : 0);} );
```

See this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

Tried other answers posted here but then I found the following to work best.

**Ascending** :

```
canvasObjects.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.z) - parseFloat(b.z) } );
```

**Descending** :

```
canvasObjects.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(b.z) - parseFloat(a.z) } );
```

Answer (score 3):

Send anonymous function to the sort method which returns a subtraction of the property "z"

```
var arr = [{z:2},{z:4},{z:5},{z:1},{z:3}];

arr.sort(function(a,b) {return a.z - b.z});
```

above puts numbers in z to order 1,2,3,4,5. To reverse the order make it return "b.z - a.z".