# Sorting vs if else if in javascript which one to choose?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, if-statement

I have a scenario in which I need to display the data in an increasing order of the index number.

```
myArray = [
{custom_carousel: false, default_label: "SmartCards", index: 3, visible: true}, 
{custom_carousel: false, default_label: "Pathways", index: 2, visible: false},
{custom_carousel: false, default_label: "Pathways", index: 1, visible: false},
{custom_carousel: false, default_label: "Pathways", index: 0, visible: false}
]
```

Should I first sort the array or add if else if condition ?

```
if(index === 0){

}else if (index === 1){

}else if (index === 2){

}else if (index === 3){

}
```

Comment: `.sort` obviously. What if you have more items in your array? Are you gonna go and change the code and add more `if`s every time that happens? *"2 or more times? Do a loop."*

Comment: Just use `myArray.sort((a,b) => a.index - b.index)` and loop through them for whatever you need them for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects) and [Sort Array based on Object Attribute - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593850)

Comment: I've commented above but reading this again I'm a bit confused. How exactly would you use the `if/else` to sort?

Comment: @adiga this is not a duplicate question. I need to know which one should be preferred.

Comment: @NikKyriakides While iterating over the loop i would compare index value in if else if whereas if i sort then i just need to iterate and show the values.

Comment: Read Nik's first comment. You won't know how many items are going to be in `myArray` when writing the code. Array size could vary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sort` method based on `index` values:

```js
myArray = [
{custom_carousel: false, default_label: "Pathways", index: 2, visible: false},
{custom_carousel: false, default_label: "SmartCards", index: 3, visible: true}, 
{custom_carousel: false, default_label: "Pathways", index: 1, visible: false},
{custom_carousel: false, default_label: "Pathways", index: 0, visible: false}
]
console.log(myArray.sort((a,b)=>a.index - b.index));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b){return a.index - b.index});
```

Will sort your array by index

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to sort the array in advance and then access by the index of the array.

**Reasons**

- easy to maintain with more elements of the array
- easy to access in wanted order
- code ie easy to understand, instead of having some code, which reason is not obvious and requieres explanation
- access is fast, instead of iterating the array always from the beginning for getting the next item.

```js
var myArray = [{ custom_carousel: false, default_label: "SmartCards", index: 3, visible: true }, { custom_carousel: false, default_label: "Pathways", index: 2, visible: false }, { custom_carousel: false, default_label: "Pathways", index: 1, visible: false }, { custom_carousel: false, default_label: "Pathways", index: 0, visible: false }]

myArray.sort(({ index: a }, { index: b }) => a - b);

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting will take O(n+log(n)) time and if-else-if-else will take O(n<sup>2</sup>) time. So sorting is better choice.

Comment: I'm not -1 but why is complexity even a question here?

Comment: Author asked which one they must choose. I give one of reasons.